# Javascript Debounce Callback Function with Dynamic Arguments

Tags: javascript, callback, debouncing

So for a feature, I have to use the javascript debounce function, which looks like this:

```
$.debounce = function (func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
      var context = this, args = arguments;
      var later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
      };
      var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
      if (callNow) {
        func.apply(context, args);
      }
    };
  };
```

I am new to callback functions and just realized, that this function returns a function that I can call. But I can not call it directly. However, I want to have dynamic arguments, without creating a new variable function object every time.

So for example I want to call my function

```
function print_something(){
// prints something
}
```

I would do it like this:

```
var print_debounce = $.debounce(print_something, 100);

And then I can use 

print_debounce();
```

But I want to have the print_debounce more dynamic.

For example (does not work)

```
var function_debounce = $.debounce(func, wait);

function_debounce(print_something, 100);
```

Is there any way to do it like this?

Thank you!

Comment: what is `var print_debounce();` ?? You can call `function_debounce` with arbitrary number of parameters

Comment: Sorry its just print_debounce();

Comment: I can not call function_debounce, with my chosen parameters somehow. Is there a different way to implement my function_debounce so it will work with an arbitrary number/value of parameters?

Comment: You can call `print_debounce(100)` just fine.

Comment: But when I created ```var print_debounce = $.debounce(print_something, 100);``` I already gave the specific parameters, so how would I call it with a different one.

Comment: @EdisonvonMatt You mean you want to make the `wait` time (after which the next call will be possible) dynamic, not the value that is passed to `print_something`?

Comment: Yes, I want the wait time to be dynamic, sorry for not being clear

Comment: For that, just move the `wait` parameter from the `debounce` function to the returned closure, so that you have to specify it every time: `$.debounce = function (func, immediate) { var timeout; return function(wait, ...args) { …`

Comment: That is probably a better and nice solution than mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, but it is not very tangible and maybe more complicated than it should.

```
var debounce_function = function (func, wait, immediate) { return $.debounce(func, wait, immediate); };

debounce_function(print_something, 1000, false).call();
```

Comment: It's returning a new debounced function every time you call debounce_function, is that correct?